# Moving FAQ block below Upsell products

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

With a paid extension that's out of it's support period I'm trying to move the Product FAQ below the Upsell Products so that the order of the blocks in the attached image becomes:

1. Product Tabs
2. Upsell Products
3. Product FAQ

   `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>`

The problem that I'm not solving is that both the tabs and FAQs are part of the product_additional_data include.

Am I better off trying to add it to the upsell_products block at the bottom or creating a new block to insert it myself.

[image: 3 blocks]

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a new block and inserting it yourself, try to think of it from a developer's point of view who has never worked on the project before.

If you see the upsell block you'll think it only contains upsells products and not FAQs. Yet if you saw two blocks, one being upsells and one being FAQs it's pretty obvious what is in both of them.